<class 'numpy.longdouble'> does not match any known type
I am getting this warning When i am trying to invoke a python method. I am not importing numpy in my codes.
/home/oracle/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy-2.1.3-py3.12-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/_core/getlimits.py:548: 
UserWarning: Signature b'\x00\xd0\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xfb\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 
for <class 'numpy.longdouble'> does not match any known type: falling back to type probe function.

This warnings indicates broken support for the dtype!
      machar = _get_machar(dtype)

What could be the reason for it? Is there any way to get rid of this warning, or resolve it?
Thanks in advance.

What method were you calling?

If you're not importing numpy explicitly, some other package is, e.g. Pandas, Scikit-learn. Which packages are you using? You're possibly using an outdated version of one of those packages. (I see you've tagged this with Pandas. What version of Pandas are you using?)

Are you using WSL?

@TimRoberts, I am calling a pandas dataframe count method.

@9769953, My pandas version is  2.2.3. I am not sure about WSL as the command for getting version of wsl is not working in my env. I am using Oracle Linux 8.

So it is WSL? In that case: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22187

I had indeed found that issue, hence my question on WSL usage. Note: I didn't ask about the WSL version, but whether you use WSL. Then again, this issue seems to pertain to WSL 1, not WSL 2. That, however, should be noticeable when you start the WSL; I'd expect the executable itself somewhere mentions it if it's WSL 2.

You said you're running Oracle Linux 8.  Are you running this on a Linux installation INSIDE a Windows system?  Or are you booting straight into Linux?  That's where the WSL question comes from.  Running Linux-within-Windows like that has some unique problems that don't arise elsewhere.

Thank you @TimRoberts, for the clarification. I am running it in straight oracle linux container.
